# Calculations with Real Numbers, Verilog HDL

Tags: numbers, verilog, hdl, real-datatype

I noticed that Verilog rounds my real number results into integer results. For example when I look at simulator, it shows the result of 17/2 as 9. What should I do? Is there anyway to define something like a: `output real reg [11:0] output_value` ? Or is it something that has to be done by simulator settings?

Simulation only (no synthesis). Example:
x defined as a signed input and output_value defined as output reg.

```
output_value = ((x >>> 1) + x) + 5;
```

If x=+1 then output value has to be: `13/2=6.5`.

However when I simulate I see `output_value = 6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code would help, but I suspect your not dividing reals at all. 17 and 2 are integers, and so a simple statement like that will do integer division.

```
17   / 2   = 8 (not 9, always rounds towards 0)
17.0 / 2.0 = 8.5
```

In your second case

```
output_value = ((x >>> 1) + x) + 5
```

If `x` is 1, `x >>> 1` is 0, not 0.5 because you've just gone off the bottom of the word.

```
output_value = ((1 >>> 1) + 1) + 5 = 0 + 1 + 5 = 6
```

There's nothing special about verilog here. This is true for the majority of languages.

Comment: I understand.. Thank you for your explanation. Now, I am wondering how can I get the result as 6.5 while calculating output_value = ((x >>> 1) + x) + 5 at x=1. I tried to adjust x=1.0 at testbench. However it did not solve my problem. Is there a way to define x input as a real number?