# Rounding off a number in verilog

Tags: verilog

Basically I'm trying to code a synthesizable module in verilog which performs division between 2 numbers and rounds off the result . For example, if I'm doing 56/30 then resulting value is 1.86 and this value should be rounded off to 2 or if I'm doing 42/30 , the resulting value is 1.4 which should be rounded off to 1 . Can synthesizable code be written in verilog to achieve this?

Comment: You need to give more detail. Which synthesiser have you got? Most will only turn the '/' operator into a divider if it's actually just a shifter - the divisor must be a constant power of two. What are your number formats? Do you understand rounding? You probably need to code a divider - look up 'non restoring division'.

Comment: Basically the numbers which I'm using for calculations are inputs to my module. So the numbers are in wire format. You mentioned that divisor must be a constant power of two . But during simulation , I got the output of the 56/30 as 1 which is the floor value of the quotient . My doubt is , can the code be synthesized if the divisor is a number other than power of 2 ?

Comment: I believe @EML was referring to the fact that if a constant or selection of divisors (denominators) were defined as powers of 2 you would get a shifter rather than a divider. A shifter being very area and power efficient in comparison to a divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the answers LSB is determined by the input format. If you change the numerator input to Fixed point with at least 1 Fractional bit rather than integers, your output will have a bit representing 0.5 which you can use to control truncate (round down) or round up.

```
module test;

reg[4:0] a = 5'b0011_0; //3 with 1 Fractional bit
reg[4:0] b = 5'b00010;  //2 no fractional bits
reg[9:0] c;

initial begin
  c = a/b ; //LSB => 0.5
  // c= 5'b01_1 => 1.5
  #1 $display("C = %b", c);
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Verilog truncates the end of a number if `<size>` is smaller than the value returned. So if you divide 42/30, the value returned is 1.4. Simply define the `<size>` as 1, and the decimal will be truncated.

However, keep in mind that this solution *truncates* the decimal, and doesn't round it up. I'm not an expert at Verilog, but you could refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745989/calculations-with-real-numbers-verilog-hdl) to further solve your problem.